# .htaccess 301 redirect, same server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I set up a website at mywebsite.net, but recently bought the domain mywebsite.com.

Now I updated the information on Google via Webmaster Tools and it recommended we set up a 301 redirect from the .net to the .com. I have found how to do this by adding code like this to the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My problem is, both domains point to the same server, so am I correct in assuming this would try to redirect even if I visited the .com initially? If so, what is the correct way to accomplish this?

It may not matter, but I didn't want to cause any problems with my search rankings.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this use case I'd add a rewrite condition (RewriteCond) to be explicit about which domain you want to impose the rule against. E.g.:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.newdomain.net [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way if the condition isn't met, your redirect won't fire. Also note that these can be chained, so you can assign multiple conditions.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#Solutions for more info. Very handy stuff lurking in that page.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine :) It doesn't work for subdirectories however, for example newdomain.net/site/ does not redirect to newdomain.com/site/ - do you know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: I _think_ if you remove the `$` symbol from the third line it will work for sub-directories.

Comment: Thanks to you both - I've edited the original post. The "$" does anchor the condition to a 'bare' hostname (specifically, the end of line), so removing it should work for you.